# unable to pass two lits to the jsp using apachi tiles

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

i am using spring mvc with Apache tile and hibernate.i pass tow lists to the jsp page.but it is print by but there's no any thing prints.

my controller class  as follows :

```
if(userExists!=0){
            model.addAttribute("Maintabs",new Maintab());
             model.addAttribute("MaintabsList",loginService.listMaintabs());
             model.addAttribute("Subtabs",new Subtab());
             model.addAttribute("SubtabsList",loginService.listSubtab(userExists));


            return "redirect:/Loginsucess";
        }else{

             model.addAttribute("error", "ERROR : invaliduser !,Please Try Again!");

             return "loginform";
        }
```

jsp page as follows (menu.jsp):

```
<c:if test="${not empty SubtabsList}">
   <c:forEach var="ob"  items="${SubtabsList}">
    <c:out value="200"/>
<%--         <c:out value="${ob.maintab}"/> --%>
<%--         <c:out value="${ob.description}"/> --%>
<%--         <c:out value="${ob.ref}"/> --%>

   </c:forEach>

</c:if>
```

i want to populate dynamic menu.please help me in jsp code.

subtab modelclass :

```
package net.ABC.form;
// default package
// Generated Jun 7, 2015 11:03:29 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Subtab generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "subtab", catalog = "ABC")
public class Subtab implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer subtabId;
    private Maintab maintab;
    private String description;
    private String ref;
    private Set<Authintication> authintications = new HashSet<Authintication>(0);

    public Subtab() {
    }

    public Subtab(Maintab maintab, String ref) {
        this.maintab = maintab;
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public Subtab(Maintab maintab, String description, String ref,
            Set<Authintication> authintications) {
        this.maintab = maintab;
        this.description = description;
        this.ref = ref;
        this.authintications = authintications;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "SubtabId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getSubtabId() {
        return this.subtabId;
    }

    public void setSubtabId(Integer subtabId) {
        this.subtabId = subtabId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MainTabId", nullable = false)
    public Maintab getMaintab() {
        return this.maintab;
    }

    public void setMaintab(Maintab maintab) {
        this.maintab = maintab;
    }

    @Column(name = "description", length = 45)
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name = "ref", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getRef() {
        return this.ref;
    }

    public void setRef(String ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "subtab")
    public Set<Authintication> getAuthintications() {
        return this.authintications;
    }

    public void setAuthintications(Set<Authintication> authintications) {
        this.authintications = authintications;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the attributes and sending redirect. It will lose all the informations that you set. If you redirect to the page it will show it right. Example:

```
if(userExists!=0){
        model.addAttribute("Maintabs",new Maintab());
         model.addAttribute("MaintabsList",loginService.listMaintabs());
         model.addAttribute("Subtabs",new Subtab());
         model.addAttribute("SubtabsList",loginService.listSubtab(userExists));


        return "successPage";
    }else{

         model.addAttribute("error", "ERROR : invaliduser !,Please Try Again!");

         return "loginform";
    }
```

If you wanna do a redirect with the data, you can use HttpSession.

```
session.setAttribute("Maintabs",new Maintab());
```

Comment: i cannot access by ob.maintab error called unkonwn "maintab"..if i reffer as <p>${ob}</p> then print as [Ljava.lang.Object;@1f43d69  how to get real values.domain classs has the mintab attribute.thaks for your answer!

Comment: Probably your list is not returning a List of Subtabs, but a List of Object... Because if you call `<p>${ob.maintab}</p>` , and your maintab attribute has getter, it should print right. When you called `<p>${ob}</p>`, it printed "java.lang.Object...", but it should print "your.package.Subtabs"

Comment: i am returning subtab objec  public List<Subtab> listSubtab(int usertype){
  List<Subtab> subtablist=(List<Subtab>)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT s.maintab, s.description, s.ref from Subtab s,Authintication a where  s.subtabId = a.subtab and a.usertype = '" + usertype + "'")
    .list();
  
  return subtablist;
  
  
 }

Comment: Does maintab has getter method?

Comment: Subtab is a hibernate model class.

Comment: Well, if MainTab is a class, you should call `<p>${ob.maintab.name}</p>`, assuming that MainTab has an attribute "name". But, you should try to print the MainTab before adding to attribute, just to check: `System.out.println(loginService.listSubtab(userExists).get(0).getMainTab());`

Comment: main tab is ok but {ob.description} and other stuff also unable to identify